# How to change the display theme in Adobe Acrobat Reader permanently?

Tags: windows, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I would like to change the display theme of Adobe Reader under windows to `Light Gray` (it is `Dark Gray` now). I did this and it works: Go to `View -> Display Theme -> Light Gray`.

**The problem** with this is that I have to do it every time I restart my PC (or close Adobe). Any way to do it permanently? Thanks.

Comment: I have changed the theme and it is still the same even after closing and reopening Adobe Reader. Try this, go to _Edit > Preferences > Documents_ and make sure the following checkbox is checked: "**Restore last view settings when reopening documents**".

Answer (score 15):

Anyone still interested see: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-night-mode-in-Adobe-reader-in-pc.

- Open Adobe Reader, go to Edit menu & select Preferences from the drop-down. Preferences window will pop up on the screen.
- Choose Accessibility from the Categories section.
- Now check the Replace Document Color box.
- In front of Custom Color Please change the Page Background to Black & Text Document to White.
- Click OK to confirm the changes.

This will give you the similar result as that of Night mode in Mobile Adobe.

Comment: This answer is completely off-topic. The question asked was whether (and how) you could make Acrobat preserve it's UI theme settings across reboots, whereas this answer teaches you to change a PDF's background display colour. One has nothing to do with the other.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the following registry key:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\AVGeneral]
"aActiveUITheme"="DarkTheme"

If you copy/paste in a .reg file and run it will work straight.

I don't know if this will be persistent but worths at least you try.

Comment: Upvoted, this answer worked for me.

Comment: This can be changed in the application through the menu View => Display Theme => Dark Gray

Answer (score 1):

For my version (2019): menu Edit->Preference->**Auxiliary tool**->Document Color Option-Replace document color - custome (dark gray as background and lightgray as text color). "Dark theme" does not change document color.